# I want to convert this array like this

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert this array ["Sleep","Wake"] to string like this  Sleep   Wake .

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php),

```
$array = ['Sleep', 'Wake'];
var_dump(implode(" ", $array));
```